# How To Set AnimatedContainer To Full Width?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to learn to make animation. I have a code to alternate between Button and CircularProgress when button is pressed:

```
       AnimatedContainer(
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
          curve: Curves.linear,
          width: _isLoading ? 60 : 350,
          height: 40.0,
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: AnimatedOpacity(
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 290),
                    curve: Curves.easeIn,
                    opacity: _isLoading ? 0.0 : 1.0,
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: MyOutlineButton(
                        label: constant.signIn,
                        onPressed: (){
                          _isLoading = true;
                          setState(() {});
                          Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () {
                            _isLoading = false;

                            setState(() {});
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    )),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: AnimatedOpacity(
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 290),
                  curve: Curves.easeOut,
                  opacity: _isLoading ? 1.0 : 0.0,
                  child: Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      backgroundColor: constant.colorWhite,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
```

I want to find a better solution to set my AnimatedContainer width when Button is displayed. I want to set it to full width without guessing or maxing the number by putting random number(in the code i set it to 350). Is there a better way to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MediaQuery.of(context).size.width to get the width of the device.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Expanded widget or flexible while using a row or column or ConstrainBox that give you an ability to constrain widget or layout builder and a bunch of other widgets with fittedBox you can control the fit.here is the [link](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/layout)
and also if you wanna create responsive UI here is the link for some useful widgets
[responsive ui](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/responsive)